# Custom Document property not getting saved in Word Document

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I have cretaed a add-in for word. I am trying to update value of a custom property in a word document on a button click. But its not getting saved.
 The code I write is:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
{
 Word.Document document = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
 Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties;
 properties = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)document.CustomDocumentProperties;
 properties["abc"].Value = "newValue";
 document.Save();
}
```

**Here if I close the document and open it again am getting the old value not the new one.**

But if I add a space in my document and then save it. Then value of custom property getting saved.
Code is:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
{
 Word.Document document = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
 Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties;
 properties = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)document.CustomDocumentProperties;
 properties["abc"].Value = "newValue";
 document.Range(document.Content.End - 1, document.Content.End - 1).Select();
 WordApp.Selection.Range.Text = " ";
 document.Save();
}
```

Why the behavior is like this. I do not want to add any extra blank space in my document. Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known "idiosyncracy" of a number of Office applications, not just Word. Changing the value of a document property, but nothing else, doesn't get "noticed", so it's not saved. There's quite a bit of detail in this [discussion on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f68f3888-6247-4906-a09e-a9c2ca5f71ad/customdocumentproperties-not-saving-with-document?forum=vsto).

Either the code needs to add something to the document "body" (which can then be deleted but *not* undone) or it can explicitly set the "dirty" flag on the document so that Word realizes it does need to save:

```
document.Saved = false;
document.Save();
```